# Get parameters from velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

I have such problem. I'm writing integration tests for my app.
In the app I send some mails for the users. When I create email I use Velocity templates.
Example of template:

> Hi ${user}!

Example of mail:

> Hi User!

When I write my integration tests I want to parse parameters from received emails. 
If I have velocity template and mail which was created with using of this template. 
I want such method

```
Map<String,String> getParameters(velocityTemplate, mailBody);
```

How I can parse parameters from emails text?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: I try. Please watch the question one more time;)

Comment: You look for chunks of text, like "Hi User!"

Comment: I look for map of parameters. In my example I want to get parameter with key="user" and value="User".

Comment: Let me get this right, you want to reverse the mail merge process, and determine what fields in the incoming email matched to parameters from you Velocity template?

Comment: You can customize velocity and get a list of the variables it references. You may also handle unfounded properties in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is like [Velocity (VM) template request parameters: Getting GET variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417505/velocity-vm-template-request-parameters-getting-get-variables) then the answer is:

```
$httpUtil.getParameterMap($httpUtil.getQueryString($request.attributes.CURRENT_URL))
```

or, as it turns out:

```
$request.getParameterMap($request.getQueryString($request.attributes.CURRENT_URL))
```

Comment: That answer is talking about Liferay.  I don't know what it is, but I'm guessing it's not relevant to this case. It didn't help me.

Comment: Liferay uses Velocity templates. Try replacing "httpUtil" with "request" or "req".

Comment: Yep, thanks. $request.parameterMap was what I was looking for.